# postresql помогите разобраться с кодом

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, резервное-копирование, dump

Есть вот такой скрипт, который снимает дамп всех баз на сервере. После снятия он помещает архивы в папки Day1, Day2 и тд.

Немогли бы вы мне прокоментировать по каждой стреке данного скрипта, что он и как делает.

В идеале хорошо бы его переписать на pg_dump на каждую базу. В стиле папка : имябазы -> day1 - файл, day2 - файл

И так на каждую базу.

Помогите чем сможете, в этой теме совсем плохо разбираюсь.

Сам скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
pg_dumpall -f /home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql
mv /home/Backup/Day1/* /home/Backup/Day2/
mv /home/Backup/Day2/* /home/Backup/Day3/
mv /home/Backup/Day3/* /home/Backup/Day4/
mv /home/Backup/Day4/* /home/Backup/Day5/
mv /home/Backup/Day5/* /home/Backup/Day6/
mv /home/Backup/Day6/* /home/Backup/Day7/
mv /home/Backup/Day7/* /home/Backup/Day8/
mv /home/Backup/Day8/* /home/Backup/Day9/
mv /home/Backup/Day9/* /home/Backup/Day10/
tar zcf /home/Backup/Day1/SQL.tar.gz /home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql
```

Comment: Какой сложный способ хранить 10 копий одного и того же дампа.

Comment: @Мелкий я его понимаю так: день1(19.07.18) - снимается копия - помещается в  Day1. день2(20.07.18) - снимается копия - помещается в Day1, а из Day1 старый файл копируется в Day2. Правильно ли это?

Comment: аа, ещё и mv же, так что одна копия и десяток пустых директорий. Вы перемещаете всё из Day1 в Day2. Поскольку имя файла не меняется - то заменяете то что было в Day2. Затем из Day2 перемещаете в Day3 и тд. В итоге будет толпа пустых директорий, сегодняшний бекап в Day1 и вчерашний в Day10. Писать скрипт настроения нет.

Comment: @Мелкий не понял про "_В итоге будет толпа пустых директорий, сегодняшний бекап в Day1 и вчерашний в Day10_"                                                                                                                 Как я понимаю данный скрипт будет сохранять 10 копий за 10 дней, всё что дольше просто не сохраняет или удаляется (не понимаю). Ну а вообще реально ли и как переписать его с `pg_dumpall` на `pg_dump`?

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov Вам же написал Мелкий, что у вас в итоге будет бекап за сегодня в Day1, бекап за вчера в Day10. Остальные с Day2 до Day9 будут пусты.

Comment: @Anamnian Нет, все базы сохранены и в той последовательности в какой я описывал. Пустых папок нет, актуальный дамп в Day1, а в остальных копии по дням уже. Этот механизм работает, но как он работает я не понимаю. Данный скрипт оставила сторонняя организация которая занималась резервным копированием и др. в моей организации.

Comment: А вообще почитайте вот [здесь](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/app-pgdump). Зело не плохо написано про то, что должно быть в `pg_dump`

Answer (score 3):

**Ваш код:**

```
#!/bin/bash
pg_dumpall -f /home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql
mv /home/Backup/Day1/* /home/Backup/Day2/
mv /home/Backup/Day2/* /home/Backup/Day3/
mv /home/Backup/Day3/* /home/Backup/Day4/
mv /home/Backup/Day4/* /home/Backup/Day5/
mv /home/Backup/Day5/* /home/Backup/Day6/
mv /home/Backup/Day6/* /home/Backup/Day7/
mv /home/Backup/Day7/* /home/Backup/Day8/
mv /home/Backup/Day8/* /home/Backup/Day9/
mv /home/Backup/Day9/* /home/Backup/Day10/
tar zcf /home/Backup/Day1/SQL.tar.gz /home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql
```

Строка 1) - Так называемый shebang (тоесть указание в какой оболочке выполнять скрипт)
Строка 2) - Команда создания дампа базы SQL (не спец, но похоже, что здесь не хватает инициализации подключения к самой базе)
Строки с 3-й по 11-ю ) Кривонаписаная попытка сохранить дампы за последние 10 дней. (почему криво, Вам в коментах популярно объяснили, это не может работать так, как Вы описываете).
И наконец последняя строка создает архив созданного во второй строке, дампа с именем SQL.tar.gz в папке "/home/BackUp/Day1"

**Попытавшись понять задачу, вижу это так**

```
#!/bin/bash
sql_dump='/home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql'
backup_dir='/home/Backup'
pg_dumpall -f "$sql_dump"
today="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
tar -czf "${backup_dir}/${today}/SQL_Dump_${today}.tar.gz" "$sql_dump"
find "$backup_dir" \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type d \
    ! -regex "${backup_dir}$" \
    -ctime +10 \
    -exec rm -f {} \;
```

*У этого варианта есть нюанс, если сделать бэкап с перерывом в 1 день (к примеру), то на выходе у Вас останется не 10 а 9 бэкапов, поскольку все бэкапы старше 10-ти дней он удалит.*

Ну или если делать как Вы предлагаете через нумерацию дней

```
#!/bin/bash
pg_dumpall -f /home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql
mkdir -p /home/Backup/Day{1..10}
for day in {10..1};do
    day_plus="$(( day + 1 ))"
    mv /home/Backup/Day{"${day}","${day_plus}"}
done
rm -rf /home/Backup/Day11
tar zcf /home/Backup/Day1/SQL.tar.gz /home/incoming/SQL_Dump.sql
```

**UPD**

В данном варианте имена баз нужно передавать как аргументы при запуске скрипта
Но вот с pg_dumpall извиняюсь не силен

```
#!/bin/bash
for base_name in "$@";do
    sql_dump="/home/incoming/${base_name}/SQL_Dump.sql"
    backup_dir="/home/Backup/${base_name}"
    pg_dumpall -f "$sql_dump"
    today="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
    tar -czf "${backup_dir}/${today}/SQL_Dump_${today}.tar.gz" "$sql_dump"
    find "$backup_dir" \
        -maxdepth 1 \
        -type d \
        ! -regex "${backup_dir}$" \
        -ctime +10 \
        -exec rm -f {} \; 
done
```

Comment: Понравился первый способ реальзации данного скрипта. не могли бы вы поянсить что происходит с строки find и до конца

Comment: Собственно начиная с `find` все это одна команда с параметрами. Это все можно записать в одну строку убрав слэши кроме последнего перед точной с запятой. Теперь по значениям параметров 1) _"$backup_dir"_ Это место где `find` будет искать папки с бэкапами 2) _`-maxdepth 1`_  глубина поиска 3) _`-type d`_ ищем только директории 4) _`! -regex "${backup_dir}$"`_ исключаем из вывода папку поиска (зачем будет понятно чуть дальше) 5) _`-ctime +10`_ находит папки измененные более 10 дней назад. 6) _`-exec rm -f {} \;`_  удаляет найденные папки

Comment: В принципе параметр _`! -regex "${backup_dir}$"`_ можно убрать, поскольку _`/home/Backup`_ будет изменяться при создании каждого бэкапа и не попадет в вывод

Comment: тааак.. надо пробовать. Большое спасибо. _В идеале хорошо бы его переписать на pg_dump на каждую базу. В стиле папка : имябазы -> day1 - файл, day2 - файл

И так на каждую базу._  Стесняюсь спросить, а по этому вопросу сможете чего либо подсказать? Просто есть сомнения, что нужно хранить именно дамп всего кластера, хотелось бы по отдельности по каждой базе

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov Добавил

Comment: а разве в последем решении не используется опять pg_dumpall? Такое ощущение, что он будет снова делать резервную копию всего кластера, а не отдельной базы переданной в параметре

Comment: Я ж написал и выше и в апдейте, что со строкой подключения и вообще бэкапа не смогу помочь. Взял Вашу за основу, хотя и сомневаюсь в правильности ее написания, поскольку при беглом чтении мана создалось впечатление, что там не хватает параметров подключения к базе.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал скрипт. Если кому интересно то код приложил. Конечно уже время много прошло, но это только из за того, что тестировал его несколько дней. В нем сразу проводится 3 дампа, анализ + чистка баз и реиндексация, так же архивы будут хранится не более 10 дней.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start backup my datebase1 `date + "%d-%m-%Y"`" >> /home/Backup/service.log
pg_dump -U postgres MyDatebase1 | gzip > /home/Backup/mydatebase1_`date \+\%d-\%m-\%Y`.sql.gz
echo "start backup my datebase2 `date + "%d-%m-%Y"`" >> /home/Backup/service.log
pg_dump -U postgres MyDatebase2 | gzip > /home/Backup/mydatebase1_`date \+\%d-\%m-\%Y`.sql.gz
echo "start backup my datebase3 `date + "%d-%m-%Y"`" >> /home/Backup/service.log
pg_dump -U postgres MyDatebase3 | gzip > /home/Backup/mydatebase1_`date \+\%d-\%m-\%Y`.sql.gz
find /home/Backup/ -type f -mtime +9 -exec rm -f {} \;
sleep 2
echo "analize datebases `date + "%d-%m-%Y"`" >> /home/Backup/service.log
vacuumdb --full --analyze -U postgres MyDatebase1
vacuumdb --full --analyze -U postgres MyDatebase2
vacuumdb --full --analyze -U postgres MyDatebase3
sleep 2
echo "start reindex datebases `date + "%d-%m-%Y"`" >> /home/Backup/service.log
reidexdb -U postgres MyDatebase1
reidexdb -U postgres MyDatebase2
reidexdb -U postgres MyDatebase3
```

Comment: reindex банально не имеет смысла сразу после vacuum full. vacuum full перестраивает индексы и так вместе с таблицами. И в целом идея достаточно сомнительна уходить в downtime и переписывать полностью содержимое баз, лучше настроить более агрессивный autovacuum, который как и pg_dump не будет мешать работе приложения с базой.

Comment: @Мелкий ну работе приложения с базой и так ничего мешать не будет, так как это всё проводится в 2 часа ночи, когда никого нет в базах. И что-то я не увидел в документации, что vacuum full проводит реиндексецию таблиц. _FULL
Выбирает режим "полной" очистки, который может освободить больше пространства, но выполняется гораздо дольше и запрашивает исключительную блокировку таблицы._ Да и думаю не будет лишним провести реиндексацию. Про автовакуум слышал, но возится с настройкой покачто не хочется. Если есть какие-то еще предложения, я был бы рад их услышать.

Comment: vacuum full переписывает целиком таблицу. Поскольку ctid несомненно меняется, то вместе с этим перестраиваются и индексы. А так же toast перестраивается. Вот здесь упомянуто о попутном перестроении индексов: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html Поэтому reindex абсолютно и полностью лишний.
То что у вас есть возможность ежедневно уходить в даунтайм - это хорошо и удобно в сопровождении. Но стоит явным образом об этом написать, многие базы себе такого позволить не могут. Всё таки SO позиционируется как база знаний.

Comment: @Мелкий да, возможно вы правы, таблицы полностью пересоздаются и вместе с ними соответственно и индексы. Спасибо за подсказку. По поводу SO учту. А что скажете по поводу того, что vacuumdb будет так часто проводится? - ежедневно (ночью).

Comment: Бессмысленная и бесполезная работы базы. Ну это мнение postgresql DBA, привыкшего к требованию непрерывной работы террабайтных баз.

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov Скажите, а вам в логе нужна дата или записть `'date + %d-%m-%Y'` вместо даты? Или сюда просто кавычки правильные не влезли?

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov И еще момент. Как думаете? Не имеет ли смысла в начале скрипта создать пеерменную типа `today="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"` и потом юзать ее по всему скрипту? Потому как в Вашем варианте таймштамп будет соостветствовть времени начала создания дампа каждой базы

Comment: @AndreyKarpov по поводу кавычек вы правы - я не смог их правильно экранировать, поэтому сделал обычные одинарные. А запись даты хотел просто видеть когда и восколько какая процедура началась. С вашей правкой, получилось их исправить. Благодарю

Comment: @AlekseyMuratov, присмотритесь к сервису [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Сервис поможет Вам избежать обидных огрехов при написании скриптов и предложит рекомендации по оптимизаци кода.